# How can I compare two corresponding columns of two sheets in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in a spreadsheet doc

sheet 1:

```
col1
123
345
565
```

sheet 2:

```
col1
123
565
789
```

output to a new sheet

sheet3:

```
col1
345
789
```

it's ok to just generate a new column in the curernt sheet.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sheet3!A1:

```
={'sheet 1'!A1:A4;'sheet 2'!A2:A4}
```

In sheet3!B2 and copied down to B7:

```
=countif(A:A,A2)>1
```

Select A1:B7 and Copy/Paste special values only. Filter ColumnB to select and delete rows `TRUE`. Delete ColumnB.

Adapt delimiters to your locale, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using match. In Sheet3 put:

```
=transpose(split(arrayformula(filter(Sheet1!$A2:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A<>"",isna(match(Sheet1!$A2:$A,Sheet2!$A2:$A,0))))&" "&arrayformula(filter(Sheet2!$A2:$A,Sheet2!$A2:$A<>"",isna(match(Sheet2!$A2:$A,Sheet1!$A2:$A,0))))," "))
```